# Site: existing record not found with SOQL

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, force.com-sites, sharing

I made a salesforce site and in its controller constructor I want to fetch a URL parameter value (the record id). The parameter will be found and it is the right record id. But when I am running the SOQL query, the record won't be found and this error occurs: 
List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Here's my code:

```
global with sharing class CampaignController {
global Kampagne__c kamp{get;set;}

global CampaignController(){
    Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('kid');
    if(id != null){
        kamp = [SELECT Name FROM Kampagne__c WHERE Id = :id];
    }

}
```

}

The object with the found id definitively exists. Is it a problem with rights on the site or what else could be the problem?

The site user has the right to read the object Kampagne__c and has also the right to read the field Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller class `CampaignController`  is using [`with sharing`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm) key words. That means, that this class enforce the sharing rules that apply to the current user. So make sure, that running user has at least read access to record with that `Id`.